# Traefik blue green deployment. Initialize web provider

Tags: traefik

I'm starting using traefik for blue/green deployment. I would like to use the REST API, so I have to put my configuration in the [web] section:

```
[web]
  address = ":8080"
  readOnly = false
 [backends]
   [backends.back]
    [backends.back.loadbalancer.stickiness]
     cookieName = "backend"
     [backends.back.servers.S000]
      url = "http://HOST_IP_ADDRESS:30000"
      weight = 1
     [backends.back.servers.S001]
      url = "http://HOST_IP_ADDRESS:30001"
      weight = 1


[frontends]
  [frontends.front]
  backend = "back"
  passHostHeader  = true
```

But it's not initialized with those values. However if I use PUT to http://localhost:8091/api/providers/web I can see the web provider OK. And if I use this same configuration for [file] it works right (but I'm unable to update it via API)

Is there any web to initialize [web] backends/frontends?

Answer (score 0):

web section is deprecated.

try this:

```
# Enable API and dashboard
[api]

  # Name of the related entry point
  entryPoint = "traefik"

  # Enabled Dashboard
  dashboard = true
```